# Is it possible to format row fill colour by a cell in an expandable way? if new job number, new row colour

Tags: conditional-formatting, formatting

I keep a to do list.
Each row has a job number.
There are several entries for each job number.
I'd like to ask google sheets to look at the job number in column.  Give the row a colour.
Every time a row shows up and that job number is different, new row fill colour.  Don't care what.  Just different.

Ideally I'd like by sheet to still have alternating colour rows. but a different shade for each job number.

I'd like for that to work so I can add job numbers and not break anything, or have to keep a list of job numbers to check against.

Also, when a job is done, if it's deleted, junk job numbers don't hang around in a formula.

Thanks.  I draft in CAD software, so not a spreadsheet expert per se.

Thank you,